# GROUP by and WHERE doesn't work together

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Why does this code work:

```
SELECT year, sum(value)
FROM test
GROUP BY year
```

And this doesn't?

```
SELECT year, sum(value)
FROM test
GROUP BY year
WHERE `user` = 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GROUP BY` needs to come after `WHERE`:

```
SELECT year, sum(value) FROM test WHERE user = 1 GROUP BY year
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
 SELECT year, sum(value) FROM test WHERE user = 1 GROUP BY year
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not expert, but try "HAVING" clause:

```
SELECT year, sum(value)
FROM test
GROUP BY year
having `user` = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert `GROUP BY` and `WHERE` clauses :

```
SELECT year, SUM(value)
  FROM test
 WHERE user = 1
 GROUP BY year
```